# Coldfusion Plugin In Sublime text

Tags: coldfusion, sublimetext3

I just moved from ColdFusion Builder to Sublime Text 3 and now I want to add the ColdFusion plug-in into my Sublime. I have googled it and found one solution that says to add the "Package Control.sublime-package " file to the installation package folder and then restart Sublime.

I did this but am not able to find a "restart" option in Sublime. Due to this I am not getting any changes on my Sublime, regarding ColdFusion.

Comment: If you installed the package, all you would have to do is If on Windows, press CTRL+Shift+P a dialogue menu will show up. Type set syntax coldfusion and press enter and it'll convert your syntax highlighting to ColdFusion.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Make sure you've installed the current CFML plugin: https://github.com/jcberquist/sublimetext-cfml. The "ColdFusion" plugin in outdated and no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

It may help someone else ...
Open the command palette ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Windows, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on a Mac) and select Package Control: Install Package . Wait for the list to open and find the CFML entry (subtitled with this github repo github.com/jcberquist/sublimetext-cfml ), then select it to install. Restart Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no restart button. Just close and re-open sublime.

edit:make sure you are opening the file as a coldfusion file. In the bottom-right corner of sublime, it says what file type is being considered. Changing this to CFML may be your solution.

edit2: removed some bad instructions that were confusing and incorrect